# Swift 3: how to sort Dictionary's key and value of struct

Tags: uitableview, sorting, dictionary, struct, swift3

This is my `Struct,`by Swift 3. I know the Dictionary **is not stored sequence** like an **Array** and that is my problem. I want to get my Dictionary sequence as I set in `ViewArray`. I can get the `ctC Dictionary`, but how can i sort the `keys` or `values` as i set in `ViewArray`
please and appreciate the help.

```
struct CTArray {
    var ctname: String
    var ctkey: String
    var ctC: [String:String]

}

var ViewArray:[CTArray] = []

ViewArray += [CTArray(ctname: "kerish", ctkey: "KH", ctC: ["mon":"Apple", "kis":"aone", "Bat":"Best", "orlno":"bOne"])]
ViewArray += [CTArray(ctname: "tainers", ctkey: "TNN", ctC: ["letGor":"one", "washi":"testing", "monk":"lasth"])]
ViewArray += [CTArray(ctname: "techiu", ctkey: "TCU", ctC: ["22":"tt", "wke":"303", "lenth":"highest"])]
```

i want to show them in my TableView Cell sorted like these:
  **the ViewArray[0].ctC.key sorted like [mon, kis, Bat, orlno]**
  **the ViewArray[1].ctC.key sorted like [letGor, washi, monk]**
  **the ViewArray[2].ctC.value sorted like [tt, 303, highest]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you are asking, but I'll offer this in case it helps.

> I know the Dictionary is not stored sequence like an Array and that is my problem.

If you want to access a dictionary by a certain order of its keys then you can create an array of just the keys in the order you required and use that to access the dictionary. An example is probably easier to follow:

Starting with one of your dictionaries:

```
let dict = ["mon":"Apple", "kis":"aone", "Bat":"Best", "orlno":"bOne"]
print(dict)
```

this output:

```
["Bat": "Best", "kis": "aone", "orlno": "bOne", "mon": "Apple"]
```

which is not what you want. Now introduce a key array and use that to access the dictionary:

```
let keyOrder = ["mon", "kis", "Bat", "orlno"]
for key in keyOrder
{
   print("\(key): \(dict[key]!)")
}
```

this outputs:

```
mon: Apple
kis: aone
Bat: Best
orlno: bOne
```

which is the order you wish.

The same idea can be used anywhere you want to use/show/etc. the keys in a particular order, by using the `keyOrder` array as part of dictionary access you are making it appear as though the dictionary entries are "stored in sequence" as you put it.

HTH

Comment: thank you for the idea, appreciate. I am still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var object1 = viewArray[0].ctC.flatMap({$0.key})
var object2 = viewArray[1].ctC.flatMap({$0.key})
var object3 = viewArray[2].ctC.flatMap({$0.value})
print(object1)
print(object2)
print(object3)
```

Outputs:

```
["Bat", "kis", "orlno", "mon"]
["letGor", "monk", "washi"]
["highest", "tt", "303"]
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but the outputs are not the sort I expect.